# Неубиваемый event в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, background-task

У меня есть постоянный объект с некоторым событием. Можно ли сделать этот объект активным на протяжении всей жизни приложения. Предположим, что объект и событие выглядят так:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.CustomEvent += _myEvent;

private void _myEvent(object sender, CustomEvent e)
{
   using (var db = new DbContext())
   {
      db.MyEntity.Add(e.Property);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Я пробовал его помещать в класс `Startup` и метод `Application_Start`. Также пробовал добавлять в `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. Как я понимаю, везде объект уничтожается и событие не происходит. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Как по вашему, кто умирает раньше, _myEvent, класс которому принадлежит _myEvent (вместе с ним же) или myObject, не отправляя событие?

Comment: Нет разницы где хранится объект. И "активных" объектов в вашем понимании - тоже не существует. У вас ошибка в том коде, который вызывает событие.

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. Но как факт событие не происходит, а если создаём объект, например, в контроллере, то всё ок.

Comment: Уточните что вы хотите сделать. Может данный механизм уже давно используется. Есть пулы к СУБД, они живут особо долго. Есть журналы, есть таймеры, что, какая у вас задача? Какое событие вы ждёте?

Comment: Событие вызывается не в моём коде. Я его лишь отлавливаю. И в контроллере могу отловить его без проблем.

Comment: А может не ваш код не хочет вызывать ваше событие, потому что оно для него чужое.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но думаю, что тут не при чём мой или не мой код. Есть проблема: как сделать так, чтобы во время работы приложения объект был так сказать не "out of scope".

Comment: А почему вы уверены, что событие вообще вызывается?

Comment: Признавайтесь уже, кто за внешний код, что за событие и зачем вы его обрабатываете. Потому что в текущем виде код совершенно рабочий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект остается живым (активным) до тех пор, пока он достижим из одного из корней сборки мусора. Корни это

- Переменные в стеке - локальные переменные тех функций, которые сейчас выполняются, и вызвавших их.
- GCHandle-s - ссылки, на управляемые объекты, закрепленные для передачи в неуправляемый код
- Статические поля

Сделайте myObject статическим полем - и он будет жить вечно.